# Updating one map in a vector of maps in clojure

Tags: vector, clojure, hashmap

I have done a lot of searching on this and not found an answer to my specific problem. As background I am taking a coding bootcamp on Java and we are learning JavaScript and Clojure alongside Java. The course content is roughly Java: 50% / JavaScript 30% / Clojure 20%.  Having advanced beyond my classmates I am tackling a challenge from my instructor.

I have built an app in Clojure to manage an animal shelter. I am using a vector of hashmaps as my central data store. Things that I have succeeded in doing:

1. Loading sample data from a hard coded array of hashmaps.
2. Creating a new animal and adding it's hashmap to the array.
3. Listing the entire "table" of animals (data from one hashmap per line)
4. Displaying a multiline detailed view of one animal's record.

What I am struggling with at the moment is my edit function. It is supposed to display the chosen animal's existing data and take any edits the user wants to make then update a working copy of the hashmap and finally update the working copy of the array.

```
(defn edit-animals [animals]
  ;; ask which animal to edit index is 1 based from the UI
  (let [index (wait-for-int "Please enter the idex of the animal to edit. Enter 0 to display the list of animals" 0 (count animals))]

    ;; if the user typed a valid index
    (if (> index 0)
      ;; then edit the animal
      (let [index (- index 1)  ;; index is 0 based for indexing the array
            animals animals
            animal (nth animals index)

            ;; prompt with existing data and ask for new data
            name (wait-for-string (str "Name: " (:name animal) "\n") false)
            species (wait-for-string (str "Species: " (:species animal "\n")) false)
            breed (wait-for-string (str "Breed: " (:breed animal "\n")) false)
            description (wait-for-string (str "Description: " (:description animal "\n")) false)

            ;; check for null returns from user
            name2 (if (= name "") (:name animal) name)
            species2 (if (= species "") (:species animal) species)
            breed2 (if (= breed "") (:breed animal) breed)
            description2 (if (= description "") (:description animal) description)

            ;; update local copy of animal
            animal (assoc animal :name name2 :species species2 :breed breed2 :description description2)]
        ;; assoc fails to update animals
        ;; assoc-in crashes at runtime
        animals (assoc animals index animal))

      ;;(wait-for-enter "\nPress enter to return to the menu")

      ;; else dispolay the list of animals
      (display-animals animals)))
  animals)
```

I have run this code in my debugger and verified that everything is working as expected up to the line:

```
animal (assoc animal :name name2 :species species2 :breed breed2 :description description2)
```

The next line fails in one of two ways as I have documented in the comments.

I am aware that atom may be a better way to do this but so far the vector of maps that is constantly passed around is working, so I would like to find a solution to my current problem that does not involve using atom. Once I get this problem solved I plan to switch the project to an atomic data structure. But is a project for another day.

If I have missed a relevant discussion here, please point me in the right direction!

Comment: you need to restructure your code, because you don't return updated animals value, but the initial value. Remember that collections are immutable

Comment: I agree that I need to restructure my code. I'm just not sure how to do that... I tried moving the last line `animals (assoc animals index animal))` inside the big `(let [] ...0` statement but got exactly the same results.

Comment: in short, you have to return the `animals` bound in your innermost `let` (it index > 0), else display current `animals` and return it. So it would be like this: `(if (> index 0) (let [...] (assoc animals index animals)) (do (display animals) animals))` but i would rather restructure it further, to be more readable and less imperative.

Comment: I cannot thank the commenters on this question enough!  I went with letwinski's solution but found both leetwinski's and Josh's contributions extremely valuable in solving both this problem and another problem that I never posted because I was finally able to solve it on my own!

Answer (score 1):

in short, you have to return the animals bound in your innermost let (it index > 0), else display current animals and return it. So it would be like this:

```
(defn edit-animals []
  (let [index ...]
    (if (> index 0) 
      ;; for an acceptable index you query for input, modify animals, and return modified collection
      (let [...] 
        (assoc animals index animals)) 
      ;; otherwise display initial data and return it
      (do (display animals) 
          animals))))
```

But i would restructure the code more, to make it more clojure-style. First of all i would extract the updating of the animal with input to standalone function, to remove `name, name2, breed, breed2...` bindings that make the `let` bindings messy. (`upd-with-input`), and replace `assoc` with `update`. Something like this:

```
(defn edit-animals [animals]
  (letfn [(upd-with-input [animal field prompt]
            (let [val (wait-for-string (str prompt (field animal) "\n") false)]
              (if (clojure.string/blank? val)
                animal
                (assoc animal field val))))]
    (let [index (dec (wait-for-int "enter index" 0 (count animals)))]          
      (if (contains? animals index)
        (update animals index
                (fn [animal]
                  (-> animal
                      (upd-with-input :name "Name: ")
                      (upd-with-input :species "Species: ")
                      (upd-with-input :breed "Breed: ")
                      (upd-with-input :description "Description: "))))
        (do (when (== -1 index) (display animals))
            animals)))))
```

then i would think of separating the whole part collecting user input from actually updating animals collection.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This code works as I was hoping. Now I just have to study it a little bit more and make sense out what it does.

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
animals (assoc animals index animal))
```

does not do what you think it does -- it is not inside the let binding vector.

First of all, good job, you asked the question the right way (with examples, etc.).  Congratulations on your coding course.  My recommendation would be to keep doing what you're doing, and learn to think in clojure in a very different way than you think in java.  They are both worthwhile, just different in approach.  In your code, you are doing numerous "temporary assignments" (such as `name2` for example).  The fact that your let binding vector has 11 pairs is a red flag that you're doing too much.  The second item in `let`, `animals animals` is particularly strange.

Instead, try to think about the evaluation of expressions rather than the assignment of values.  `name2 = name1 + ...` is a statement, and not an expression.  It doesn't do anything.  Instead, in a declarative language, almost everything is an expression.  In the code below (which I just an extension of what you've done and not necessarily how I'd do it from scratch), note that no local bindings are re-bound (nothing is "assigned to" more than once).  `let` allows us to lexically bind `name` to the result of an expression, and then we use `name` to achieve something else.  `not-empty` allows us to do better than using `name` and `name2`, which is what you have done.

```
(def animals [{:name "John" :species "Dog" :breed "Pointer" :description "Best dog"}
              {:name "Bob"  :species "Cat" :breed "Siamese" :description "Exotic"}])

(defn edit-animals
     [animals]
     (if-let [index (dec (wait-for-int "Please enter the index of the animal to edit. Enter 0 to display the list of animals" 0 (count animals)))]
       (let [animal (nth animals index)
             name        (or (not-empty (wait-for-string (str "Name: " (:name animal) "\n") false)) 
                             (:name animal))
             species     (or (not-empty (wait-for-string (str "Species: " (:species animal) "\n") false)) 
                             (:species animal))
             breed       (or (not-empty (wait-for-string (str "Breed: " (:breed animal) "\n") false)) 
                             (:breed animal))
             description (or (not-empty (wait-for-string (str "Description: " (:description animal) "\n") false)) 
                             (:description animal))
             animal {:name name :species species :breed breed :description description}]
         (println "showing new animal: " animal)
         (assoc animals index animal))
       animals))

(def animals (edit-animals animals))
```

Note that this does not really achieve much other than restructuring your code.  It really does too much, and is not a good example of how a function should do one thing well.  But I think your goal for now should be to be a little more idiomatic and get away from the imperative mentality, when you write your clojure.  After you do that, you can focus on the design part of it.

Keep up the good work and ask any more questions you have!

Comment: THANKS. you've given me some things to muddle with.  I agree that I did not do things perfectly. this is my very first Clojure project and I know I still have a ways to go before I am truly proficient.

Comment: @cptully Good job -- by the way, consider at least upvoting answers here that you have found helpful that we have taken the time to submit

Comment: I was in lecture all morning. My instructor did bring up this post though to show off my question and your response.  I will be testing the answers and working on my app tonight.  and I will most definitely up vote the helpful one(s).

Comment: I just tried your code and leetwinski's code and both work as I was expecting my code to work. Now I will be working on understanding how they work.  In particular, I had not yet stumbled on or been introduced to `if-let` or `letfn` so I need to read up on them and make sense out of the sample you have kindly sent me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to delete `animals` from

```
animals (assoc animals index animal))
```

at the end of the `if` statement and instead return the result of the function

```
(assoc animals index animal)
```

or display them

```
(display-animals (assoc animals index animal))
```